# in shiny, can I pass the input value from a widget to change the layout?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a layout with 3 columns with widths 2, 5 and 5. In the column of width = 2 there are widgets and I would like to change the width of the other 2 columns depending on what is chosen in a widget, for example to widths 2, 7, 3.

I would have to pass the input value to the ui.R with something like this:

```
column(width = 2, ...),
column(width = a, ...),
column(width = b, ...)
```

a and b will depend on input values or combination of input values

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: might be possible within renderUI. Have never tried it for columns before

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. With renderUI you change one output, I want to change the layout of the columns to rearrange everything in it

Comment: You can pass any UI element through `renderUI`, even columns. You'd have to use it to wrap pretty much your whole UI, though, so there may be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alistaire answer put me on track (thanks!), I post here a reproducible working example that might help others.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(
      width = 2,
      radioButtons("radio", "Column widths",
                   choices = list("2-3-7" = 1, "2-7-3" = 2
                   ))
    ),
    uiOutput("columnMid"),
    uiOutput("columnRight")
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {      
  output$contentL <- renderText("Content to the left")      
  output$contentR <- renderText("Content to the right")

  output$columnMid <- renderUI({
    if (input$radio == 1) w <- 3 else
      if (input$radio == 2) w <- 7 else return (NULL)

    column(
      width = w, align = "center",
      textOutput("contentL")
    )
  })

  output$columnRight <- renderUI({
    if (input$radio == 1) w <- 7 else
      if (input$radio == 2) w <- 3 else return (NULL)

      column(
        width = w, align = "center",
        textOutput("contentR")
      )
  })
})
```